# Jenkins pipeline stuck on Build

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a few services running on a Kubernetes cluster on ibmcloud and I use Jenkins to deploy these services.

So, until yesterday everything was working fine, but today as I tried to re-deploy my services 2 of them got stuck on "BUILD", freezing Jenkins, and the only way to get Jenkins to work again was by running "systemctl restart jenkins" on the remote machine where jenkins is installed.

After restarting Jenkins I went into the failed build[image: failed pipeline]

The end of the console output was:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (BUILD)
[Pipeline] sh
+ yarn build
yarn run v1.16.0
$ yarn clean && tsc
$ rm -rf dist/
Done in 7.25s.
[Pipeline] sh
+ yarn build:webpack
yarn run v1.16.0
$ webpack --config webpack.config.js
Resuming build at Fri Mar 13 23:00:58 UTC 2020 after Jenkins restart
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Global Slack Notifier try posting to slack. However some error occurred
TeamDomain :
Channel :build-info
Message :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: JENKINS-50407: no loaded shell in CpsFlowExecution[Owner[isa-v2/user-service/2:isa-v2/user-service #2]]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've tried to delete pipeline and create it again, updated jenkins but still no luck. 
Truth is I don't really know much about Jenkins and I'm getting kind of desperate here! :x

It was working fine yesterday, no code was changed, no Jenkins configuration or pipeline changes eithe. It just seems to have started out of nowhere.

Could someone please help me figure out what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Never saw this error... But it seems to me that you have same symptoms like the ones exposed here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52966?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel -> Forever running job, nothing changed (only updating Jenkins), simple pipeline... Maybe you can try the steps in the last comment (1. Update the jenkins.xml file to use a 64bit JRE, 2. increase max heap size to 1024m for the JRE (in the jenkins.xml file), 3. increase the stack size to 4m in the jenkins.xml as well (-Xss4m))

Comment: @AdamBarreiro no luck :/ same problem keeps happening. Thanks for trying to help me tho ! :)

Comment: @BrunoLira are you sure that you are not using a "latest" reference somewhere?
For me this looks like after the jenkins restart, Jenkins may has not the same version as before or did some automatic plugin updates. 

You need to take care about versioning there as jenkins has a lot of internal dependencies.

E.G if you restart a Pod in K8s, it could be that a new image gets taken.

Comment: I am not :( 
Anyway, I had to deploy my services so I've started doing it manually, after a few days it started working again! I'm afraid I have no idea what happenned :O